# Owl carousel doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

After I updated my sources codes, my carousel doesn't work anymore. The images that I click, supposedly open with images slider (Carousel), but now open a new link to new image.

```
<div id="owl-carousel-works" class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
     <div class="item">
          <div class="latest-item col-md-12" >
              <a href="images/screenshots/MainPage.png" title="screen #1" data-lightbox-gallery="screenshots-gallery">
              <img src="images/screenshots/MainPage.png" class="img-responsive" alt=""/>
              </a>
          </div>
      </div>
  <div class="item">
       <div class="latest-item col-md-12 " >
            <a href="images/screenshots/7.png" title="screen #2" data-lightbox-gallery="screenshots-gallery">
            <img src="images/screenshots/7.png" class="img-responsive" alt=""/>
            </a>
       </div>
  </div>
```

Included all stylesheets

```
<link href="css/owl-carousel/owl.carousel.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/owl-carousel/owl.theme.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/owl-carousel/owl.transitions.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Included all javascripts

```
<script src="js/modernizr.custom.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/responsive-nav.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/nivo-lightbox.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.appear.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.inview.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.animateNumber.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.fitvids.js"></script>
<script src='js/jquery.scrollTo.js'></script> 
<script src="js/wow.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/script.js"></script>
<script src="js/fastclick.js"></script>
<script src="js/scroll.js"></script>
<script src="js/fixed-responsive-nav.js"></script>
```

There is not errors in my javascript file. Below is my configuration toward owl-carousel...

```
/* screenshot slider */
var owl = $("#owl-carousel-works");
owl.owlCarousel({
    itemsCustom: [
        [0,1],
        [900,2],
        [1800,3],
        [2700,4],
        [3600,5],
        [4500,6]
    ],
    navigation: false
});

// Nivo Lightbox
$('#screenshots a').nivoLightbox({
    effect: 'fadeScale'
});

// team carousel
var owl = $("#owl-carousel-team");
owl.owlCarousel({
    itemsCustom: [
        [0,1],
        [900,2],
        [1800,3],
        [2700,4],
        [3600,5],
        [4500,6]
    ],
    navigation: false
});
```

Comment: What did you update ?

Comment: Check console for errors - it could be a good start...

Comment: @RobinLeboeuf I'm updated smooth top bar scroll and mobile responsive only.

Comment: @nevermind Error mentioned above.